# How to fix -resources.sh: line 7: realpath: command not found in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcodeproj

I'm setting up a new project with pods. Where do I need to set the path for below error

```
-resources.sh: line 7: realpath: command not found
```

Comment: There is no `realpath` command in standard macOS, afaik. Please show the full build step/script that generates this error, and also your Podfile.

Comment: I have this error too. Here is the full content of my `Pods-ColaGoods-resources.sh` on [Github Issue](https://github.com/qmint/notes/issues/7)   @Gereon  would you help us?

Comment: @Gereon: Apparently it depends: [Is the Unix "realpath" command distributed with macOS Ventura?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450035)

Answer (score 20):

If you have Homebrew you can fix this with `brew install coreutils`

Answer (score 16):

Simply cleaning build folder (Product -> Clean Build Folder) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly old question, but here is my fix for those who come later:

- Clean build folder
- Exit Xcode
- Run `pod deintegrate`
- Run `pod install`
- Restart Xcode and clean again

Always fixes this problem.